# Having issues in writing text files

Tags: java, file

I am using the `FileWriter` class to write text files in Java.

The "\n" is not working, so to overcome this I used the `BufferedWriter` class and its method `newLine()`. It helped me getting onto next line but alas, it always go on modifying my previous file. I want every time when I run my program a new file to be generated!

Please someone help me on this part. Why is that "\n" not working? What is the possible solution to my problem?

```
FileWriter write = new FileWriter ("D:/final project/report.txt", true);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter (write);

bufferedWriter.write("Current Time : " + hour + ":"+ minute + ":" + second + " " + am_pm);
bufferedWriter.newLine();
bufferedWriter.write("Current Date : " + date + "/"+ (month+1) + "/" + year + "  d/m/y ");
bufferedWriter.newLine();
```

Comment: You hardcoded the file name, so *why* do you think it should create a new file each time?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Maybe he means he wants the file to be overwritten each time.

Answer (score 3):

You've really got two entirely orthogonal problems here...

> I want every time when I run my program a new file to be generated!

Well currently this is how you're creating the `FileWriter`:

```
new FileWriter ("D:/final project/report.txt", true);
```

That's using the [constructor overload with an `append` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29), which you're setting to `true`... suggesting you *want to append to an existing file*.

If you *don't* want to append to an existing file, why are you specifying `true` for that parameter? Either specify `false` instead, or just use an overload which doesn't have that parameter, and overwrites the file by default.

Personally I would strongly advise against using `FileWriter` directly - I'd use `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter`, so that you can specify the encoding. Otherwise it will use the platform default encoding, which is rarely a good idea IMO. (Personally I tend to use UTF-8 when I have the choice.)

> Why is that "\n" not working?

It's working in that it's writing the `\n` character (U+000A) to the file. But whatever you're using to *read* that file presumably isn't treating that as a line break - because the line break on Windows is usually `\r\n`. `BufferedWriter.newLine()` will use the platform default line break, which is why that's working.

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct line separator:

```
String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileOutputStream  and wrap it in  DataOutputStream

```
    FileOutputStream fo=new FileOutputStream("c:/xyz/report.txt");
    DataOutputStream ds=new DataOutputStream(fo);

    ds.writeBytes("Current Time : " +new Date() );
    ds.writeBytes(System.getProperty("line.separator")+"Current Date : " +new Date() );
```

Answer (score -1):

Java terminates each line with a carriage return  and line feed  instead of just a line feed. That is Java terminates using "\r\n" instead of "\n".

Comment: Java uses whatever the platform default is when you use `BufferedWriter`. But *Windows* uses `\r\n` instead of `\n`.